# сохранить изменения из propertyGrid в ListBox

Tags: wpf, propertygrid

Собственно все просто, есть ListBox который биндится через ItemsSource к ObservableCollection. Так же есть PropertyGrid который биндится к SelectedItem этого ListBox'а. Так вот штука в следующем, когда меняю что либо в PropertyGrid то в Item ListBox`a эти изменения тут же появляются (биндинг всетаки). Но стоит мне выбрать другой Item в ListBox'e то все изменения пропадают, возвращаются прежние. Есть подозрение что это PropertyGrid чудит (отменяет изменения), но нагуглить не смог. Может кто подскажет куда копать?

Comment: возможно ошибка в коде, покажите разметку xaml и ваш код

Comment: Вся проблема была в валидации Catel. Убрал с ObservableCollection кателевский атрибут [Model] и все заработало как часики.